# Несколько картинок в ImageLoader

Tags: java, android-studio

подскажите пожалуйста как можно получить и отобразить несколько картинок в ImageLoader.
Сейчас я получаю одну картинку ,но мне хотелось бы получать несколько картинок и затем при просмотре переключаться между картинками для лучшего представления продукта.
Это отрывок  ImageLoader :

```
 private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) 
{
    File f=fileCache.getFile(url);

    //from SD cache
    Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
    if(b!=null)
        return b;

    //from web
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap=null;
        URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(40000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(40000);
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
        Constant.CopyStream(is, os);
        Constant2.CopyStream(is, os);
        Constant3.CopyStream(is, os);
        os.close();
        conn.disconnect();
        bitmap = decodeFile(f);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Throwable ex){
       ex.printStackTrace();
       if(ex instanceof OutOfMemoryError)
           memoryCache.clear();
       return null;
    }
}
```

А это Активность:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // when finish parsing, hide progressbar
        prgLoading.setVisibility(8);
        // if internet connection and data available show data
        // otherwise, show alert text
        if((Menu_name != null) && IOConnect == 0){
            sclDetail.setVisibility(0);

            imageLoader.DisplayImage(Constant.AdminPageURL+Menu_image, imgPreview);

            txtText.setText(Menu_name);
            txtSubText.setText("Цена: " +Menu_price+" "+ActivityMenuList.Currency+"\n"+"Статус: "+Menu_serve);
            txtDescription.loadDataWithBaseURL("", Menu_description, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
            txtDescription.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e7e7e7"));
        }else{
            txtAlert.setVisibility(0);
        }
    }

 public void parseJSONData(){

    try {
        // request data from menu detail API
        URL url = new URL(MenuDetailAPI);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setConnectTimeout(20000);
        connection.setReadTimeout(20000);
        connection.connect();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

        String line;
        String str = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null){
            str += line;
        }

        // parse json data and store into tax and currency variables
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
        JSONArray data = json.getJSONArray("data"); // this is the "items: [ ] part

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject object = data.getJSONObject(i); 

            JSONObject menu = object.getJSONObject("Menu_detail");

            Menu_image = menu.getString("Menu_image");
```

Это отрывок xml Активности  :

```
<pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgPreview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/loading" />
```

Если кому понадобится то могу предоставить больше кода.